# How do I reference a function using its name in a string

Tags: string, excel, function, vba

I am looking to make reference to a function using only a string that contains the function's name. I have looked at callbyname and application.run but I am unsure as to where I am going wrong.

Any thoughts?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDynamic1()
  Debug.Print "TestDynamic 1"
End Sub

Sub TestDynamic2()
  Debug.Print "TestDynamic 2"
End Sub

Private Sub TestDynamic3()
  Debug.Print "TestDynamic 3"
End Sub

Sub callTestDynamic(i As Integer)
  On Error GoTo DynamicCallError
  Application.Run "TestDynamic" & i
  Exit Sub
DynamicCallError:
  Debug.Print "Failed dynamic call: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Public Sub TestMe()
  callTestDynamic 1
  callTestDynamic 2
  callTestDynamic 3
  callTestDynamic 4
End Sub
```

All I get are the errors saying that the macros do not exist.

What I want to be able to do is

```
function testFunction(functionName as string)
    run functionName
end function

sub testSub()
    *... some code here ...*
    testFunction "test"
end sub

function test()
    debug.print "This function works"
end function
```

Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Putting your code in a normal module made it run correctly for me. TestDynamic 1, 2 and 3 worked and the non-existent TestDynamic4 caused an error as expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Function Calls in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845944/dynamic-function-calls-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score -1):

You have some naming inconsistencies...

Also using 'test' as a function doesn't work

```
Sub testSub()
    '*... some code here ...*
    testFunction "test1"
End Sub

Function testFunction(functionName As String)
    Application.Run functionName
End Function

Function test1()
    Debug.Print "This function works"
End Function
```

> Note: OP references the following code: [Dynamic Function Calls in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845944/dynamic-function-calls-in-excel-vba)